# Bat: Set command not working inside parenthesis

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, command

I've come across this strange behavior of bat commands:

```
Set path=%path%;C:\Myfolder;
```

works perfectly fine. But when I put this inside parenthesis it behaves strangely:

```
if defined WINDIR (set path=%path%;C:\Myfolder)
\NVIDIA was unexpected at this time.
```

or even

```
(set path=%path%;C:\Myfolder)
\NVIDIA was unexpected at this time.
```

Please note that

> C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common

is part of my Path environment variable.

What's wrong with using () here?

Comment: When the line is placed _inside_ parentheses you have to enclose the path assignment in quotes: `(set "path=%path%;C:\Myfolder")`; otherwise the parentheses of the `%path%` closes the one in the line, so the next part marks an error.

Comment: Thanks Aacini.. It worked. Please post it as answer. I will mark it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `set` command is placed inside parentheses, then the `%path%` expansion puts a right parentheses that closes the original; that is:

```
set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common

(set path=%path%;C:\Myfolder)
```

When the `%path%` variable is expanded in the second line, this is the result:

```
(set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Myfolder)
```

You may see that the right paren in `(x86)` part closes the original left paren, so the next part in the line is `\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Myfolder)` that is the cause of the error.

To avoid this error, just enclose in quotes the value in `set` command:

```
(set "path=%path%;C:\Myfolder")
```